# Flask send_file() sending empty text document

Tags: python, flask

I'm loading some data from a database and inserting it into a text file, but just as a proof of concept I'm using dummy data, but I can't seem to get the text file to download with any content.

```py
@app.route("/results", methods=["GET"])
def results():
    if request.method == "GET":
        with open("output.txt", 'w') as file:
            file.write("Test 1 2 3")
            return send_file("output.txt", as_attachment=True, cache_timeout=0)
```

The text file downloads but its empty? HOWEVER, looking in the directory where the file is created, there is text in it!?

It's as if the file is downloading before it's finished writing?

Comment: I'm guessing you are sending a string. What about sending the actual file? `return send_file(file, as_attachment=True, cache_timeout=0)`

Comment: Try to move the line `return send_file("output.txt", as_attachment=True, cache_timeout=0)` to the `with` indentation level. This will make sure the file is closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opening the file for reading in the binary mode worked for me.

Try changing the last line from

```
return send_file("output.txt", as_attachment=True, cache_timeout=0)
```

to

```
file_to_be_sent = open("output.txt", 'rb')
return send_file(file_to_be_sent, as_attachment=True, cache_timeout=0)
```

Comment: just to be safe, add the argument `mimetype="text/plain"` of `send_file` function